# How to get wchar_t** arguments in clang?

Tags: c, clang

There is no `wmain` but I want to use unicode arguments.

Is it possible to do in `clang` and how?

Comment: It looks like in clang and gcc on Windows, arguments to `main` are in UTF-8 (at least in cygwin). This is regardless of the code page and locale environment. Or so my tests tell me.

Comment: @n.m. that is untrue for native Win32 applications.

Comment: What kind of Clang are you using? Is it a Windows only question? With Visual Studio or MinGW? What version?

Comment: @rubenvb it's general question, I want version that will work on both windows and linux

Comment: @Heather why would you want `wchar_t**` on linux?

Comment: @rubenvb I just want my code to work there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just transfrom `argv` into unicode?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t **wargv = malloc(argc * sizeof(wchar_t *));
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        wargv[i] = malloc(/* enough size - see below */);
        mbstowcs(wargv[i], argv[i], /* the size */);
    }

    //...
}
```

You can do `malloc` with enough size to store the string and do `realloc` to shrink-to-fit, or You can use `mbtowc` on each element of `argv[i]` rather than use `mbstowcs`.

Comment: Thank you but I want to pass unicode symbols to my application also

Comment: @Heather Just pass! (..like `shell> myprog arg1 家 arg3 집`) Why are you confused?

Comment: This assumes that `argv[i]` contains a multibyte encoded string

Comment: @MattMcNabb Could you explain in detail?

Comment: @ikh (1) if the person types in non-ascii, the OS might not actually pass through a UTF-8 or Big5 or whatever encoding is in use; (2) mbstowcs uses the locale to know which multibyte encoding to decode, so the program might need to set the right locale first (C programs don't default to the environment's locale).  Your code is certainly an idea although if OP can get `wmain` working then it would avoid a few potential pitfalls.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh, you're exactly right. (I didn't know C doesn't set its locale properly..) Then, I think we should use some non-standard feature. Based on a bit googling, I think clang doesn't support something like `wmain`, and I hope OP's platform has something like `GetCommandLine` win32 api >o<

Comment: @ikh, alternatively, set the locale explicitly according to the environment: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`.